# Passing parameter to app() expression not working in application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm trying to pass a variable to the app() expression in application insights logs

1. app('identifier').requests - works
2. let e='identifier';
   app(e).requests

Does not work with an error
Query could not parse at 'app' on line [2,0]

Tried double quotes, escaping toscalar, tostring... Always the same result.

Thank you everybody

Comment: I don't think it is possible. I think 'identifier' needs to be hardcoded...

Comment: Yes but why? Why would it be like this?

Comment: provided context as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm a part of Application Insights team)

It is not possible (at least today). This limitation comes from this context:

There is an engine which runs raw KQL queries against resources. The engine doesn't know anything about "app" keyword.

There is something like preprocessor which analyzes a query and determines against which resources actually to run a query (and removes "app" from a query). This preprocessor cannot run KQL queries (at least today) and as a result it is not possible to use KQL to come up with dynamic resource identifiers.

Comment: Thank you, I marked your answer as correct as this is not possible for the time being